# asp-for is overriding when I use autocomplete="one-time-code."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

When using the "autocomplete='one-time-code'" attribute alongside the "asp-for" attribute, it appears that the "asp-for" attribute is being overridden, resulting in unexpected behavior. The "asp-for" attribute is commonly used in ASP.NET to establish a binding between a form input and a corresponding model property. On the other hand, the "autocomplete" attribute is used to control whether a form input should have autocomplete functionality enabled or disabled.

In this particular scenario, the conflict arises when attempting to use both attributes simultaneously. It seems that the "autocomplete" attribute takes precedence over the "asp-for" attribute, causing the binding to be disregarded. As a consequence, the expected synchronization between the form input and the model property may not occur as intended.

Comment: Not sure what you're actually asking here?

Comment: Use autocomplete="new-password" for enabling password suggestions or autocomplete="off" to disable autocomplete

Comment: I couldn't replicate the problem. It worked for me. Can you paste in the final full input tag from developer tools both with and without the autocomplete?

Comment: Hi @durai rai, could you pls share enough code which could reproduce your issue?

Comment: <input asp-for="Firstname" class="form-control" autocomplete=one-time-code />
In this particular scenario, the conflict arises when attempting to use both attributes simultaneously.